# Comparing two different XML files in Java via same nodes that they both have

Tags: java, xml

I have two different XML files to compare,

Let's say I want to compare the specific content of these XML files,

For example:

Each of these XML files has a common node called:

```
<BURAK>
   <burak1>
      <burak2>a<burak2>
<BURAK>
   <burak1>
      <burak2>c<burak2>
```

So, I want that node in java and compare both the node names and content names of these nodes and validate them.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("/abc.xml");
    {
        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("/def.xml");

        BufferedReader source = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis1));
        BufferedReader target = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2));

        XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
        List differences = compareXML(source, target);
        printDifferences(differences);
    }
}

public static List compareXML(Reader source, Reader target) throws SAXException, IOException {
    //creating Diff instance to compare two XML files
    Diff xmlDiff = new Diff(source, target);
    //for getting detailed differences between two xml files
    DetailedDiff detailXmlDiff = new DetailedDiff(xmlDiff);
    return detailXmlDiff.getAllDifferences();
}

public static void printDifferences(List differences) {
    int totalDifferences = differences.size();
    System.out.println("===============================");
    System.out.println("Total differences : " + totalDifferences);
    System.out.println("================================");

    System.out.println(differences);

}
```

I found a helpful code to create this structure but this code gives me all the differences between two files.
What I want is go to a specific node and compare the specific child nodes in that node.
How can I write that kind of code in Java?

Regarding the suggestion of "svasa" I changed the code in that way:

```
try {
    String firstValue = null;
    String secondValue = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = db.parse(new File("/abc.xml"));

    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//TOC/STRUCTURE/TOC_NODE/NODE_NAME");

    Object exprValue = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);

    if (exprValue != null) {
        firstValue = exprValue.toString();
    }

    Document doc1 = db.parse(new File("/def.xml"));

    XPathFactory xPathFactory1 = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath1 = xPathFactory1.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr1 = xpath1.compile("//TOC/cac:STRUCTURE/cac:TOC_NODE/cac:NODE_NAME");

    Object exprValue1 = expr1.evaluate(doc1, XPathConstants.STRING);

    if (exprValue1 != null) {
        secondValue = exprValue1.toString();
    }

    if (firstValue != null && secondValue != null) {
        System.out.println(firstValue);
        System.out.println(secondValue);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is not working or somehow I can't make it work. If this is the correct structure in terms of what I want. The code looks logical to me. As I mentioned in the comment I need a second path definitely. The structure looks similar not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`XPathFactory`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZybnj8pfUAhVB4iYKHcoEAMYQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjavax%2Fxml%2Fxpath%2FXPathFactory.html&usg=AFQjCNGiO5fSZYUMKVt4KZTMsMgdb3Pjww&sig2=l-lIk5rxPvKTsU7xZ_CtpA). Its easy to code, compile an xpath expression and use it to extract the data you need from xml.

Code would be :

```
 try {
    String firstValue = null;
    String secondValue = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = db.parse(new File("/abc.xml"));

    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//BURAK/burak1/burak2");

    Object exprValue = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);

    if (exprValue != null) {
        firstValue = exprValue.toString();
    }

    doc = db.parse(new File("/def.xml"));

    exprValue = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);

    if (exprValue != null) {
        secondValue = exprValue.toString();
    }

    if (firstValue != null && secondValue != null) {
        System.out.println(firstValue);
        System.out.println(secondValue);


    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The xpath `//BURAK/burak1/burak2` goes to the `burak` node and gets you the value as a `STRING`, when you specify the result to be `XPathConstants.STRING`

Because your two xmls are similar , the same xpath expression would work.

Try executing the code, you will get the values `a` and `c`, then you can compare.

Comment: The cod seems logical but unfortunately they are smilar not excatly the same so i should define another xpath expression for the other file as well to match them.

Comment: If you update question with second xml we can see if another xpath is needed

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    File inputFile = new File("abc.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory
            = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "NODE";

    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :"
                + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("NODE_NAME: "
                    + eElement
                    .getElementsByTagName("NODE")
                    .item(0)
                    .getTextContent());
            System.out.println("NODE: "
                    + eElement
                    .getElementsByTagName("NODE")
                    .item(0)
                    .getTextContent());


            File inputFile1 = new File("def.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory1
                    = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder1;

            dBuilder1 = dbFactory1.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc1 = dBuilder1.parse(inputFile1);
            doc1.getDocumentElement().normalize();


            XPath xPath1 = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String expression1 = "NODE1";

            NodeList nodeList1 = (NodeList) xPath1.compile(expression1).evaluate(doc1, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int j = 0; j < nodeList1.getLength(); j++) {
                Node nNode1 = nodeList1.item(j);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :"
                        + nNode1.getNodeName());
                if (nNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode1;

                    System.out.println("NODE: "
                            + eElement1
                            .getElementsByTagName("NODE_NAME")
                            .item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("NODE: "
                            + eElement1
                            .getElementsByTagName("NODE_NAME")
                            .item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my answer for this problem.Thank you "svasa" for the ideas.